# How to add a List with a TabView that has a List inside in SwftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-tabview

I am wanting to add a TabView with a List, inside another List. The issue is that adding a list with a TabView that has a list inside makes it so that the view is small. Can't figure out if this scenario is possible.

The reason it needs two List is because i am going to add the Tab Selector as a sticky header, which comes built in by using `Section` inside the List.

```
@State private var selectedTab = 1
var body: some View {
    List {
        // TAB SELECTOR
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {selectedTab = 1}) {
                Text("First Tab")
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {selectedTab = 2}) {
                Text("Second Tab")
            }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {selectedTab = 3}) {
                Text("Thrid Tab")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        
        // TABS
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Text("First Tab View")
                .tag(1)

            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 20) { index in
                        Text("This is index \(index)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .tag(2)

            Text("Third Tab View")
                .tag(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a list instead of a vstack? ie, do you need the user to be able to edit the list?

Comment: TabView is really not designed to be part of List - it is expected to be on root level. I don't think you'll make it work properly as in code in question.

Answer (score 0):

First off, on my machine I have troubles make those button work to switch tab, but if that work for you I'm ok. In my testing changing tab only worked when using the tabItem modifier. By the way, I've found a way to make the the tab View stay to the bottom of the View using a combination of GeometryReader and overlay:

```
@State private var selectedTab: Int = 1
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geom in
        let size = geom.size
        List {
            // TAB SELECTOR
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {selectedTab = 1}) {
                    Text("First Tab")
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {selectedTab = 2}) {
                    Text("Second Tab")
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {selectedTab = 3}) {
                    Text("Third Tab")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .safeAreaPadding(.top) // <-- Only iOS 17 (I think). Use padding top if running on lower versions
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            // TABS
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Text("First Tab View")
                    .tag(1)
                    /// On my machine only this works to change tabs
                    /*.tabItem {
                        Text("1")
                    }*/
                
                VStack {
                    List {
                        ForEach(0 ..< 20) { index in
                            Text("This is index \(index)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .tag(2)
                
                Text("Third Tab View")
                    .tag(3)
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: size.height - 10)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Now, let me know if this is ok for you. As I said, switching tabs on my machine did not work as expected placing buttons there as a header. Maybe the List is the culprit, I don't know exactly why is acting like that. When you tap a header button it executes all the actions of those buttons at a time.